# how to use get_user_meta function in Contact Form 7

Tags: contact-form-7

i am beginner in wordpress development i wish to add current user data and get user meta function as a input of the text field. can you please help me out.

```
Your Name: [text* your-name readonly default:user_display_name]
Your E-mail: [email* your-email readonly default:user_email]
House: [text* data value="<?php echo get_user_meta( $userID, 'user_registration_house', true); ?>"] 
<label> phone     [text* phone ] </label>
<label> House NO     [text* house ] </label>
[submit "Submit"]
```

i wish to take input value from get_user_meta( $userID, 'user_registration_house', true);  as default value. help me out with directly from contact form 7 code or via function hook.
thanks